# Display logo or image in the Ribbon using VSTO

Tags: excel, vsto, ribbon, ribbon-control

I am customizing a ribbon in the Excel using VSTO. I want to display a logo which is of stamp size in a ribbon. I tried the button which is not visible enough. The logo has some text in it and could not read when I use button.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA command bar has the option to display image but unfortunately Microsoft doesn't have any controls to display image in Ribbon using VSTO. But I used a button and made it disabled ever and displayed image still it is not nice as VBA.