# Can MS Office Ribbons hold a Picture Box?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsto

My question is pretty simple, can I put a picture box in a MS Ribbon Customization (VSTO add-in).  I can tell that it's not a readily available option from the designer, but can it be done from the XML?  I haven't found an examples that do it.

The end goal is to have an image run out to the right of the controls in the ribbon, which would quickly allow someone walking behind a series of users see "which team they were on"/"program version" they were using.

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744797/display-logo-or-image-in-the-ribbon-using-vsto

Comment: @Kiru other than a no vote, no not really. A button, even at the larger sizes, can't handle a very large image.  It also seems a little off to be forced to use a button for this.